# AWS Glue/Data catalog showing quotes around data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

When I query my files from Data Catalog using Athena, all the data appears wrapped with quotes. Isit possible to remove those quotes?

[image]

I tried adding `quoteChar` option in the table settings, but it didnt help

[image]

**UPDATE**

As requested, the DDL:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `holidays`(
  `id` bigint, 
  `start` string, 
  `end` string, 
  `createdat` string, 
  `updatedat` string, 
  `deletedat` string, 
  `type` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'quoteChar'='\"') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://pinfare-glue/holidays/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER'='pinfare-holidays', 
  'averageRecordSize'='84', 
  'classification'='csv', 
  'columnsOrdered'='true', 
  'compressionType'='none', 
  'delimiter'=',', 
  'objectCount'='1', 
  'recordCount'='29', 
  'sizeKey'='2494', 
  'skip.header.line.count'='1', 
  'typeOfData'='file')
```

Comment: Are you querying csv data? Do you use [OpenCSVSerDe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv.html)?

Comment: @YuriyBondaruk yes

Comment: Can you post the DDL of your table here?Can you confirm if properties are matching as shown below:  CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE myopencsvtable (
   col1 string,
   col2 string,
   col3 string,
   col4 string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   'separatorChar' = ',',
   'quoteChar' = '\"',
   'escapeChar' = '\\'
   )
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://location/of/csv/';

Comment: @bdcloud updated OP

Comment: Can you try below DDL with all columns to create table and see if it's ignoring quotes ?   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `holidays`(
  ....   .....    .....`type` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'separatorChar' = ',', 'quoteChar' = '\"', 'escapeChar' = '\\') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://pinfare-glue/holidays/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1')

Answer (score 8):

I know its late but I think the issue is with the "Serde serialization lib"
In

> AWS GLUE --> Click on the table --> Edit Table --> check "Serde serialization lib"
> it's value should be "org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde"

> Than Click Apply

This should solve your issue. Below is a sample image for your reference.

> 

[image]